# How can I check the type of an object against a list of types?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Given a collection

```
IEnumerable<Type> supportedTypes
```

What's the best way to check whether a given object is one of those types (or a derived type)?

My first instinct was to do something like:

```
// object target is a parameter passed to the method in which I'm doing this.
if (supportedTypes.Count( supportedType => target is supportedType ) > 0)
{
    // Yay my object is of a supported type!!!
}
```

..but that doesn't seem to be working.  Can I not use the "is" keyword in a lambda expression like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so in the course of typing the question and doing some more experimenting to make sure I wasn't asking something really stupid, I realized an easy solution.  Posting here in case somebody else ever does something equally stupid. ;-)

You can't use the "is" keyword in your lambda expression, but you can use:

```
supportedType => supportedType.IsInstanceOfType(target)
```

yielding:

```
if (supportedTypes.Count( supportedType => 
supportedType.IsInstanceOfType(target)) > 0)
```

```
if (supportedTypes.Any( supportedType => 
                              supportedType.IsInstanceOfType(target)))
// object target is a parameter passed to the method in which I'm doing this.
{
    // Yay my object is of a supported type!!!
}
```

hat-tip to Bob Vale for noting in the comments below that I should have been using .Any(...) rather than .Count(...) > 0

Comment: You should use Any() instead of checking the count

Comment: As a side-note, I find myself wanting to mentally parse something like `a.IsInstanceOf(b)` as _"is a an instance of b?"_ - which of course in this case is backwards.

Comment: Are you sure `IsInstanceOf` is the one you want? `IsAssignableFrom` sounds more like you want really. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx

Comment: @asawyer No, IsAssignable works where the target is a type, IsInstance works where the target is an object and you wish to detirmin its type

Comment: I think `IsInstanceOfType` (noting I mis-typed the method name in the answer.. edited and fixed) is what I want here as I am being handed an already-instantiated object reference.  It seems like to use `IsAssignableFrom` I would have to explicitly take that object and ask what type it is which seems like an extra operation unless I'm missing something..?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `Contains` and `target.GetType`?

```
bool ar isSupported = supportedTypes.Contains(target.GetType());
```

or `Any`

```
bool isSupported = supportedTypes.Any(t => t == target.GetType());
```

(don't use `Enumerable.Count` if you just want to know if a sequence contains a matching element, that is rather inefficient if the sequnce is large or the predicate is expensive)

**Edit**: If you want to take inheritance into account you can use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
var isSupported = supportedTypes.Any(t => target.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

- The `is` operator is used to check whether an instance is compatible to a given type.
- The `IsAssignableFrom` method is used to check whether a Type is compatible with a given type.

> Determines whether an instance of the current Type can be assigned
>   from an instance of the specified Type.

Comment: The problem with .Contains or an explicit check for equality with `target.GetType()` is that it won't handle inherited types.  supportedTypes may include `Fruit` and I need the test to succeed for `Apple` or `Orange`